# How to declare a constructor with a void Action<T> property as taking in a method with a parameter?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have the following code:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    public Action? Method(<T> x) { get; set; } = null;

    public MenuItem(string title,Action Method(<T> x)
    {
        Title = title;
        Method = Method(<T> x)
    }
}
```

I want my `Method` property to take in a parameter of a certain type, be it any given, which can be passed in both the constructor and later invoked (or called by a 3rd method) in another class.

I have tried declaring the `Method` property with parameter brackets and thought about doing it in the constructor in the same way, which doesn't run. Would using an `Action` be the right way of doing this? The specific method pertaining to the instance of the object will also be declared in the class supposed to call the Action from the property.

EDIT:
I have tried the solution proposed by @Mike Nakis and the IDE seemingly is able to run the code but produces a type conversion error. Here is the code run in sequential order.

```
public static void CallGUI()
{
         RepoController controller = new RepoController();
         Menu lager = new Menu("WELCOME");
         lager.MenuItems.Add(lager.DictTKey, newMenuItem("MENU", 
         CreateNewProductItem(controller)));
}

public class Menu
    {
        
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
        public int DictTKey { get; set; } = 0;
        public Dictionary<int,MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int,MenuItem>();

        public Menu(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
        public void AddMenuItem(string title,Action<RepoController> method)
        {
            MenuItems.Add(++DictTKey, new MenuItem(title, method));
        }
    }

public class MenuItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
        public Action<RepoController>? Method { get; set; } = null;

        public MenuItem(string title,Action<RepoController> method)
        {
            Title = title;
            Method = method;
        }
    }
```

A type conversion happens in CallGUI():

```
lager.MenuItems.Add(lager.DictTKey, newMenuItem("MENU", CreateNewProductItem(controller)));
CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to System.Action.<T>'
```

Comment: Should your "method" have a return type or is it `void`?

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand this syntax that you invented. Can you show how you intend on using this `MenuItem` class?

Comment: @Progman The 'Method' property, defined as being a void Action, is supposed to also be void but take in a parameter (be it any given type)

Comment: @Sweeper The main point is to take a user input and call a void method (with a parameter) from an instantiated object containing the certain method defined earlier in the class

Comment: Can you [edit] and explain this with some *code*? It's still a bit unclear to me, but I think Mike Nakis' answer is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the following work for you?

```
public class MenuItem<T>
{
    public string Title { get; set; };
    public Action<T>? Method { get; set; };

    public MenuItem( string title, Action<T> method )
    {
        Title = title;
        Method = method;
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is the Action called is supposed to be void, but must take in a method with a parameter of a certain type <T>. As far as I understand the Action<T> determines the return values of the Action - is this correct (supposed to be void in this case)?

Comment: No, this is not the case.  You are thinking of `Func<R>`, which returns `R`.  On the other hand, `Action<T>` accepts `T` and returns `void`.

Comment: I have tried editing the code (edited my original response) - the IDE does not complain any longer but throws a type conversion error when trying to add a new instantiation of the object to a collection defined in another class

Comment: Ah yes, the usual problem with generics in C#. What we usually do in these cases is that we derive our generic class from a non-generic abstract base class, and then we declare the collection to be a collection of the non-generic abstract base class instead of the generic one.